# Why RestAPI occasionally returns 429 TooManyRequest response?

Tags: c#, rest

I send a request to the API and sometimes receive the response with an HTTP 429 status code (*TooManyRequests*).

On average, for 10 requests, 2 will return 429 response and the remaining 8 return the correct value.

It also happened to me that when it was the first request (so there is no option for *TooManyRequests*)

```
public static List<ResponseObject> GetProductsFromRestAPI(int[] ProductIdArray )
{
    List<ResponseObject> products = new List<ResponseObject>();
    string action;

    for (int i = 0; i < ProductIdArray.Length; i++)
    {
        action = "products/" + ProductIdArray[i].ToString();
        client = AddHeadersToClient(action, new RestClient("https://api.usedbythiscode.com/")); //required by this API.
        var currentProduct = RequestsLib.GetProduct(client, action);
        products.Add(currentProduct);
    }

    return products;
}

public static Product GetProduct(RestClient restClient, string action) //todo test this for bugs
{
    var result = new Product();
    var request = new RestRequest(action, Method.GET);
    var response = SendRequest(restClient, request);//Here I sometimes get response with 429.

    //.. Other code
    return result;
}

public static async Task<IRestResponse> SendRequest(RestClient restClient, RestRequest request)
{
     return await restClient.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
}
```

Temporarily resolved it by sending another request with do while loop and usually second request return right answer.

```
 do
 {
     SendRequest(restClient, request);
 } 
 while (StatusCode != 200);
```

Where could the cause of the error lie?

Is it possible that I have unclosed requests?

Is creating multiple RestSharp clients a good practice?

EDIT:
The problem was on the server side. All I had to do was report the bug to the admins who provided the API. Thank you for help.

Comment: Sounds like the API doesn't like you calling it as much as you are. If it returns an `Retry-After` HTTP response header, you could use that to see how long you should wait before trying to call it again.

Comment: just a wild guess: probably because you've sent too many requests? i suggest asking whoever's running the API. and, when in doubt, retrying.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the 429 error: you're not using async  properly. `SendRequest` is marked as `async` and returns a `Task<T>`. You need to await that Task, which means that the calling method (GetProduct) needs to be marked as `async` and return a Task. Which means the method that calls that `GetProductsFromMCM` needs to be marked as `async` and await the result of `GetProduct`. Async grows in your code - you need to let it. Do *not* use .Result, .Wait(), .GetAwaiter().GetResult() or any other technique besides `await` to get the results.. You're just going to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: I suggest you watch [8 await async mistakes you SHOULD avoid in .NET by Nick Chapsas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQu-eBIIh-w).

Comment: It looks like I should say I understand error 429. I don't understand why it occurs in my case since I don't exceed API limits.
@MartinCostello thanks, you pointed me in a nice direction, but it doesn't get that header. It will be for the future.
FranzGleichmann 
No, as I mentioned, even if I send one request, sometimes response is equal 429. The API itself resets every midnight. The limit is 100k queries, where I did not ask
never more than 1k requests.
mason thanks a lot, but this code is fast refactor for SO purposes. Currently i read Concurrency in c# cookbook from Stephen Cleary.

Answer (score 1):

[429 is Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). Most APIs have some kind of rate-limiting in place so that a single client can't take down their server with too many requests.

The proper response for 429 is to retry. I recommend [using Polly for retry logic](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait), but be aware that [`HandleTransientHttpError` doesn't consider 429 a transient error](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Extensions.Http/issues/26).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @mason, you should use **async** method with **Task<>** and **await response** Here is the part of login side of my mobileApp-project in Xamarin. You may want to see how to use async with Task<> easily.

```
 public async Task<BSUser> ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        string url = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get(Constants.URL_KEY, "") + "/api/Validateuser";
        HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();

        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          {"userName", userName},
          {"password", password}
        };

        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _Client.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try {
                    var responseData = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData).ToString();
                    UserInfo userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(result);

                    BSUser value = new BSUser();
                    value.UserName = userInfo.userCode;

                    return value;
                }
                catch (Java.Net.SocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hata", e);
                    return null;
                    
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (SystemException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```